# How to divide the iphone screen into a proportion of four different UIView( respect to screen height) using IOS UIstackview distribution proportional

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uistackview

How can i divide iphone screen height into 4 different UIView with height as 0.2 * screenHeight, 0.3 * screenHeight, 0.3 * screenHeight and 0.2 * screenHeight respectively. for this i m using stackview with constraints 0 for top,bottom,trailing and leading, distribution is proportional. but as i do equal heights for views and set multiplier into required as mention above it gives me error saying that UIViews y-axis is not set. How can i resolve [this is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCy7S.png)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeAjG.png)

Comment: What gives you an error? Interfacebuilder? or?

Comment: updated the question with screenshot

Comment: You can zip the project and upload it to google drive or something and I can help you, but there is no way I can help solve this here, you have too many constraints that are conflicting

Comment: https://github.com/Feroz-Istar/viksitIOSApp.git this is link and LoginStoryboard is file name

Comment: I just added a new pull request, and you can review and merge

Comment: Let me know if that is what you wanted:)

Comment: @Ladislav thanks a ton its worked i need to calculate height from main superview/safe area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set stackview top, left, bottom, right constraints to 0.

Set stackview Distribution to fill.

Set stackview Spacing to 5

For view1 with 0.2 height set bellow constraints

- Equal height to stack view; Constant: -3.75; Multiplier: 0.2
- Equal height to view4

For view2 with 0.3 height set bellow constraint

- Equal height to stack view; Constant: -3.75; Multiplier: 0.3

We have used 15 pixels for spacing. So we need to divide these 15 pixels equally in all 4 views i.e. 15/4 = 3.75

Bellow is the link for solution

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nudo593mjhsxmn4/viksitIOSApp-master_Solved.zip?dl=0

Comment: i have followed your steps but when i set view 2 height equals view 3 height its giving constrain conflicts on height constraints of all views

Comment: if i delete the view 4 or views 3 height then i m not getting constrains conflicts

Comment: Give equal height constraint to either view1 and view 4 or view 2 and view 3. Don't give 2 equal height constraints

Comment: yeah but what happen to the view whose height is not given will it take . the remaining and expected height

Comment: We are setting view1 and view4 same height and setting view1 height = 0.2 so total space occupied by both views will be 0.4. Now we are setting View2 height = 0.3 so now remaining space for view3 is 0.3. The reason you are getting error while setting both height constraint is we have removed 15 pixels now to adjust all other view in remaining space any one view's height value may vary with minor value.